# Start the build if build fails using batch script

Tags: svn, batch-file, tortoisesvn

In make file i added some batch script commands. i want to execute that commands if it fails in any line executet the next line. 
Example:

```
    @echo #pragma DATA_SECTION(abcBuild, "xyBuild")>$(ABC_BUILD_INFO_FILE)
@svn info > test.txt
@echo char abcBuild[] = { >> $(ABC_BUILD_INFO_FILE)
@echo "Build Date & Time: %DATE% %TIME%\n"  >> $(ABC_BUILD_INFO_FILE)
@type test.txt >> $(LTE_BUILD_INFO_FILE)
@echo }; >> $(LTE_BUILD_INFO_FILE)
$(MAKE) -C $(ABC_TEST_MAK_PATH) DEVICE=$(DEVICE) DL_UL=$(OUT_FILE)
```

If i give wrong option in 2nd line(SVN info--> svn infoo) it  showing error and getting out. But i want execute the next step.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure how your makefile is processed, "maybe" this could help

```
@svn info > test.txt 2>nul | break
```

If your make program complains in the `break`, use this

```
@svn info > test.txt 2>nul | ver > nul
```